# Get yahoo friends list using hello js

Tags: javascript, yahoo, yahoo-api, hello.js

I am using hello.js for listing all my friends in yahoo.Following is the function used on button click :

```
getFriends('yahoo', 'me/friends')
```

I generated yahoo api key for my application.While generating api key I have checked all checkboxes given under permissions.The api key is used in the script as given below,

```
hello.init( {
        yahoo : 'YAHOO_CONSUMER_KEY'
    }
    , {
        redirect_uri:'APPLICATION_URI',
        oauth_proxy : 'https://auth-server.herokuapp.com/proxy',
        scope:"friends"
    }
    );
```

Following is the error I am getting now.

```
code:"parameter_rejected"
message:"401 could not authenticate"
```

Can someone please help me to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

We had an issue with `scope` parameters in Yahoo's OAuth1 implementation, try seeing if the error goes away if you dont define a `scope`